# "financed" process in Activity Monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, launchd, ventura, activity-monitor

I noticed a process in Activity Monitor called `financed`. If I turn on the Kind column it shows "Apple" but so do all the other processes. If I use the hierarchical view no parent or children are shown for it. Using View > Inspect Process I see that its parent process is `launchd`.

If I try to Google it, I mostly get results talking about financing a Mac. What is this process?

This is an M2 Macbook Pro running Ventura 13.4.

Comment: It’s Apple’s new “feature” that locks out your device if you miss an Apple Card payment.  It will be integrated with Find My to aid in repossessions.

Comment: @Allan: Seriously? Can you post a link?

Comment: That was meant to be facetious!  It’s another one of Apple’s barely (if that) documented processes.

Comment: The `kind` = `Apple` column indicates that the binary is Apple Silicon, nothing to do with it being an OS process. The other value you'd see there is `Intel` for code translated by Rosetta2.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths: I understand that, but I didn't claim that it indicated that it was an OS process. The conclusion to draw from my statement about "Kind" is that I don't have any Intel/Rosetta process - and more particularly that `financed` is not one.

Comment: I am just clarifying the use of that column, not just for you (because on my first reading it occurred to me you may be equating it, and you had given no indication to the contrary), but for others who may search for similar questions, and get the wrong end of the stick. With that in mind, that information in your question is superfluous as you state you are already aware it doesn't indicate an OS process. Why else mention it? You might now want to edit the OP to forestall any confusion.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths: I included all that I explored in trying to gather information on this process. I was just trying to be thorough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As with many of the launchd processes, the manpage gives the answer:

```
% man financed

DESCRIPTION
     financed financed supports passd in managing Apple Pay and Wallet operations. It cannot be used directly by the user.
```

Comment: *%$&@!* The one place I failed to look!

Comment: (In case it's not obvious: the trailing `d` indicates that this is a [dæmon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)) — a background process that runs continually, waiting to provide some service to other processes — related to finance in this case. This naming convention is widely used in macOS and other Unix-related OSs; ‘launchd’ is another example.)